# Java null element in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I just had a simple question that google is being unable to resolve. So if I set some of the elements of an `ArrayList` are set to `null`, will they still be counted in `list.size()`, and will the indices for the remaining elements still remain intact?

If not, can any of you advise as to how I can do that?

Comment: Yes and yes. Some test code would have shown you that :)

Comment: Yes, they will. You could have noticed this yourself if you would have taken the time to type a few lines of code. You will have to manually loop over the list to create a new one with only the non-empty entries.

Comment: Why would one want to set elements of a list to null?!

Comment: Perhaps I have to be enlighted, but I don't see any use.

Comment: trying it would have taken you less time than to ask the question

Answer (score 6):

Yes, take a look on a `add()` method implementation, for example:

```
public boolean add(E object) {
    Object[] a = array;
    int s = size;
    if (s == a.length) {
        Object[] newArray = new Object[s +
                (s < (MIN_CAPACITY_INCREMENT / 2) ?
                 MIN_CAPACITY_INCREMENT : s >> 1)];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, newArray, 0, s);
        array = a = newArray;
    }
    a[s] = object;
    size = s + 1;
    modCount++;
    return true;
}
```

Since `ArrayList.size()` returns just the value of `size` variable, it's clear, that if you add `null`, the size will be increased by 1, so, yes, `null` is counted.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all the elements from your list

```
MyList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
MyList.size();
```

Reference: http://www.mhaller.de/archives/12-How-to-remove-all-null-elements-from-a-Collection.html

Comment: Yes, you can, although that doesn't have anything to do with this question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and Yes, you can verify it with this simple code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add("" + i);
    }
    System.out.println(list.size() + " " + list);
    list.set(0, null);
    System.out.println(list.size() + " " + list);
}

10 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
10 [null, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the null element will still be counted in the size of the list and the indices of the remaining element will remain intact.

Answer (score 0):

It's a **bad idea** to infer class behaviour from test code or reading the source code, also because ArrayList is not final and the class you obtain may be an extended version of ArrayList with a different implementation.

Just read  List and ArrayList contracts, that must be mantained in the extending classes:

[**List:**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

An ordered collection (also known as a sequence). ... 
Some list implementations have restrictions on the elements that they may contain. For example, *some implementations prohibit null elements, and some have restrictions on the types of their elements*.

[**ArrayList:**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Resizable-array implementation of the List interface. Implements all optional list operations, and *permits all elements, including null*.

the contract says that ArrayList permits null elements, so the answer to you question is yes, the list size and indices remains intact.